# React Native - Native iOS module crashes when opening Settings app

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm trying to create a simple React Native module which will allow me to open the iOS settings application from within a React Native application.

My implementation:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RNOpenAppSettings.h"

@implementation RNOpenAppSettings

- (dispatch_queue_t)methodQueue
{
    return dispatch_queue_create("com.krazylabs.RNOpenAppSettings", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
}

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(OpenAppSettings)

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(open){
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
}

@end
```

The above actually does open the iOS settings application but then crashes almost immediately. My first assumption was that perhaps the operation was taking too long and blocking the React Native queue; which is why I'm creating a separate queue. This did not help.

Has anyone run into this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by calling openURL asynchronously using GCD. Hopefully this helps someone else.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RNOpenAppSettings.h"

@implementation RNOpenAppSettings

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(OpenAppSettings)

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(open){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
    });
}

@end
```